# Scroll images aligned absolutely, data attribute held in the button for the slider position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I have so far

```
<div onclick="scrollhideandshow(l, 1);">
</div>
<div id=image1 style="left: 100px;">
</div>
<div id=image2 style="left: 550px;">
</div>
function scrollhideandshow(dir, data) {
      if (data>0 && data < 6) {
        if(dir == 'l') {
          $('#image' + data).fadeOut(1000)
          $('#image' + (parseInt(data)+1).toString()).css('left' = $('#image' + data).css('left'))
          $('#image' + (parseInt(data)+2).toString()).css('left' = $('#image' + (parseInt(data)+1).toString()).css('left'))
        } else {
          $('#image' + (parseInt(data)-2).toString()).css('left' = $('#image' + (parseInt(data)-1).toString()).css('left'))
          $('#image' + (parseInt(data)-1).toString()).css('left' = $('#image' + data).css('left'))
          $('#image' + data).fadeOut(1000)
        }
      }
    };
```

And it's telling me

```
scrollhideandshow(...) is not defined
```

Ultimately the edge images should fade out and the buttons on either side should direct the animated transition

Comment: please share your full code